# How do I access the Response Headers using ServiceStack

Tags: javascript, redux, servicestack

I'm using react with Redux toolkit but I'm unbale to access the Response headers

```
return await client
.get(new Users())
.then((data) => {

// how to I access the Response Header here?
  console.log("data", data);
  return data;
})
.catch((error) => {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to [ServiceStack's TypeScript Service Client](https://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-add-servicestack-reference), the public API of which you can find on [index.d.ts](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client/blob/master/src/index.d.ts#L288) where you can use the instance `requestFilter` and `responseFilter`:

```
export declare class JsonServiceClient {
    //...
    requestFilter: (req: IRequestInit) => void;
    responseFilter: (res: Response) => void;
}
```

To inspect the underlying W3C [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API's [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) / [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), e.g:

```js
let client = new JsonServiceClient();
client.responseFilter = function(r) {
    console.log(r.headers)
}

client.get(new Users())
    .then(...)
```

Comment: Cheers for that! I was aware of that but I had the syntax all wrong.

Out of interest is there way of setting this globally in JavaScript?

Comment: @Leon I've just added support for `JsonServiceClient.globalResponseFilter` in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client/commit/ba581894bfe901732067b756c7f29cf13cb4aea1) which is available from [@servicestack/client v1.0.59](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@servicestack/client) on npm if you're using a npm project otherwise you can fetch the latest version on npm from [unpkg CDN](https://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-add-servicestack-reference#cdn-unpkg)

Comment: Oh Wow! Cheers!